# Tornado python REST api with multiple handlers but same parameter types

Tags: python, json, rest, tornado

i am making an application with Tornado (using Tornado-JSON).
My goal is to make rest service that returns JSON and can just handle whatever is passed in parameters - search/find if you want (trying to feed emberjs with JSON for different parameters passed) for example:

```
class ServicesHandler(CorsMixin,APIHandler):
....
__url_names__ = ["services"]

class ServicesTenantHandler(ServicesHandler):
    def get(self, tenant_id):
    ....

class ServicesIdHandler(ServicesHandler):
    def get(self, id):
    ....
```

And this is what i get in routes for example above:

```
  [
    "/hostedservices/services/(?P<id>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$",
    "<class 'sysinfo.hostedservices.ServicesIdHandler'>"
  ],
  [
    "/hostedservices/services/(?P<tenant_id>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$",
    "<class 'sysinfo.hostedservices.ServicesTenantHandler'>"
  ]
```

However i cannot make it receive anything but /hostedservices/services/***SOME_VALUE***

and in this case everything is useless because the second class (ServiceIdHandler) is always invoked.

I am quite new to all python and tornado but shouldn't i be able (according to routes) to invoke in this way:

/hostedservices/services/?tenant_id=VALUE
or 
/hostedservices/services/?id=value

surely i will have bunch of more attributes but somehow when i test it from soapUI it seems that i always have to pass 1 parameter as part of URL path (template style parameter) rather than regular parameter and because of that i cant make it to have 2 handlers with same attribute types (but different attributes)

i would appreciate all the help i can get at this point...

Thanks!

Comment: Hey! This is a bit late, but I just wanted to chime and say that I'm rewriting customizable routing for Tornado-JSON (for v2.0) to make it much easier and clearer (I'm the author).
The branch has had work on it for quite a while but I've just been really busy and haven't had as much time to work on it.
If you're interested to see where it's heading, you can check out some comments I've left for myself at the bottom of the diff so far here (https://github.com/hfaran/Tornado-JSON/compare/master...routing_refactor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This routing should solve your problem:

```
[
  "/hostedservices/services/tenant/(?P<id>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$",
  "<class 'sysinfo.hostedservices.ServicesTenantHandler'>"
],
[
  "/hostedservices/services/(?P<id>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/?$",
  "<class 'sysinfo.hostedservices.ServicesIdHandler'>"
]
```

The route */hostedservices/services/tenant/VALUE* will be generated for *ServicesTenantHandler* and the route */hostedservices/services/VALUE* will be generated for *ServicesIdHandler* (instead of /hostedservices/services/?tenant_id=VALUE or /hostedservices/services/?id=value routes).

In order to obtain this result, the handlers must be:

```
class ServicesHandler(CorsMixin, APIHandler):
    __url_names__ = ["services"]
    ....

class ServicesTenantHandler(ServicesHandler):
    __url_names__ = ["services/tenant/"]

    def get(self, id):
    ....

class ServicesIdHandler(ServicesHandler):
    def get(self, id):
    ....
```

Comment: Thank you! This does answer my question though im fighting with figuring out how to do a full search with every attribute inculded potentially. As an alternative i started using handler.get_argument() to get arguments and use them as search parameters...